# Mixed integer linear Programming in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to solve this Mixed integer Linear programming problem using MATLAB. However, I am having issues with the definition of summation of linear objective function and decision variable in matlab.  I am using the intlinprog function in MATLAB. Please find image link below.

[image: Image showing Mixed integer linear programming question]

Please also find a snippet of my code written in MATLAB.  I am getting an error as I observed "fun" cannot be used with MATLAB intlinprog function.

```
for i = 1: length(bt)    
f(i,1) = bt(i) + nch*w;
f(i,2) = (w/nch) - st;
f(i,3:5) = 0;
end
M = [4,5,9,10,14,15,19,20,24,25,29,30,34,35,39,40,44,45,49,50,54,55,59,60,64,65,69,70,74,75];
e = 0.00001;
A = [0 0 0 1 1;
     -nch 1/nch 1 0 0];
ACell = repmat({A}, 1, 15);
A = blkdiag(ACell{:});
B = [1; 0.7];
ub = ones(5,1);
ub(1:2,1) = 2.3;
ub = repmat(ub, length(bt),1);
lb = zeros(5,1);
lb(3,1) = 0.01;
lb = repmat(lb,length(bt),1);
f = reshape( f.' ,1,numel(f))';
B = repmat(B,length(bt),1);
Opt = opti('f',f,'ineq',[],[],'eq',A,B,'bounds',lb,ub,'xtype',M)
[x,fval,exitflag,info] = solve(Opt)
```

Comment: You should add a small complete example of your attempt in code so that people can test it and spot errors.

Comment: `fun` should be a vector of length `n` where `n` is the total number of variables in the model. `fun[j]` is the objective coefficient of variable `j`.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, though i have no idea on how to implement the summation of the objective function in MATLAB. Could i use the sum function in matlab and then minimize the objective function?

Comment: You need to cast the problem in matrix format, i.e. no summations. See [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/10/matlab-vs-gams-integer-programming.html) for an example.

Comment: I have been able to define my problem in a matrix format but i am stuck on implementing a decision variable for the intlinprog function in matlab.

Comment: `linprog` and `intlinprog` do not need you to pass on a vector of variables `x`. They know the size of `x` from the data. `x` will be returned as function result. I really would suggest to read the (rather excellent) documentation of `linprog` and `intlinprog` much more carefully.